# What is the windows registry for JRE autodownload option in the Java Control Panel?

Tags: registry, java

I want to set the JRE autodownload option found on the advanced tab of the Java Control Panel in Windows XP to 'Always Auto-Download' on a very large number of machines. What is the windows registry key name for this option and the value for 'Always Auto-Download' ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look for the `C:\Documents and Settings\<USER_NAME>\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties` file.

Add line `deployment.javaws.autodownload=NEVER` after `#deployment.properties` if you want to set JRE Auto-Download to *Newer*.

Add line `deployment.javaws.autodownload=PROMPT` after `#deployment.properties` if you want set JRE Auto-Download to *Prompt User*.

Or delete `deployment.javaws.autodownload` option if you want set JRE Auto-Download to *Always*.